# What is the methodology or pattern used to create a ReactJS front end that is more or less a series of components you can turn on/off

Tags: reactjs

First off, sorry if this is the wrong Exchange to post this question to.

What is the methodology or pattern used to create a ReactJS front end that is more or less a series of components you can turn on/off dynamically. I have worked with a handful of larger companies in the past couple years, and a few of them have built off some pattern that allows them to create components that can be modularized and spread across different teams to work on. Where you don't need the whole of the product to develop against, only the modular piece you are assigned to. From which you can override whats being served remotely with something locally.

I would like to build based on this methodology for my own projects but have no idea where to begin in reading about the logic they are using to essentially build npm packages for each component, and then override the remote with the local for dev sake.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer this honestly ReactJS is a powerful framework which was meant to be reusable and modular throughout the whole pages of website by request for new components whenever there needs to be a change in rendered output This is where react has surpassed Angular.
If you are thinking about reusable methodology to make your projects develop faster and easiler,  Atomic design by  [Brad frost](https://bradfrost.com/) is the best way to execute this mission .here is a brief example on atomic design:..
Consider a website (maximum of 30 pages) ; Each components of the entire website can be
basically divided into  atoms, molecules, organisms , templates and pages  where pages form the website

**atoms**: atoms are the basic building blocks of any webpage eg: texts , links ,  images , icons , buttons
**molecules** : Composed of atoms  (or molecules sometimes) which repeats  eg : a title  and a subtitle tag

with same styles which can repeat in other pages or a button and  text and many more

**organisms** : organisms are individual sections of a page which are mainly composed of atoms and molecules and even other organisms in rare cases . They are repeated in same page or multiple pages eg : header or footer

**templates** : Templates are composed of atoms molecules and organisms  which provide a basic structure of how content should appear in every page which is normally same for most of the websites  Eg : header and footer together

**pages** : combinations of all the above components

Below React  snippet  contains  part of bootstrap atomic design  , BEM methodology

```html
render(){
  return (
    <div className="card  ch-molc-body-card">
      <CardList name="card-body ">
        <h1 class="ch-atom-h1 ch-molc-body-card__h1">hello there</h1>
        {
      this.state.monsters.map(monster =>(<h1 key={monster.id}>{monster.name}</h1>
      ))}
      </CardList>
      
  </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the breakdown of React. It is something I use frequently. What I am trying find out, is what build methodologies, practices, concepts are out there to use with React. I have seen a few. But the large scale ones I have seen, allow for companies to server a remote copy of the service itself, and distribute only smaller pieces of the service to various teams to work on those pieces. And these pieces can be added or removed at will, and even overriden with locally ran versions of the components for development.